# Idea terminal sees outdated maven version

Tags: java, windows, maven, intellij-idea

I upgraded maven version. What I've done:

1. Downloaded new maven version
2. Updated `PATH` environment variable
3. In idea selected new maven version:
   [image]

Inside cmd I see correct maven version:

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\apache\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Also I see correct version in Idea maven plugin:

[image]

But when I try to check maven version in the terminakl I see:

[image]

How could I acheve that Idea terminal sees new maven version ?

**P.S.**

shell config:

[image]

Comment: In terminal settings do you have custom shell path? Search for shell path in settings. if you have custom shell path as a batch file check that you are setting different path there

Comment: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam I didn't change default values but could you please explain how could I check it ? I see that command **set path** output is different from cmd and from idea terminal

Comment: Try restarting IDE after changing the environment variable in OS. If you use Toolbox App for launching the IDE try also restarting the Toolbox App.